# Can not prevent Text Object from being Wrap-FastReport

Tags: .net-core, fastreport

in fastreport Dot Net Core the property ( WordWrap = false ) does not prevent textobject from being wrapped. it seems the behavior is exactly like ( WordWrap = true ). but in the desktop version the property work as expected.

it could be tested on web site (( https://www.fast-report.com:2016/razor/Home/Designer  )).

is it possible to prevent text wrap in web dot net core?